# How to refresh ExpandableBaseAdapter on ChildItems changed

Tags: android, xamarin.android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have following part of the code of GroupExpand event where I would like to start intent service and notify data set changed on the broadcast receiver. I was able to get refreshed data set OnReceive() method of the broadcast receiver but attendanceExpListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() did not work for me.

AttendanceExpandableListFragment.Cs

```
      public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
..........
 // create new adapter at first and set it
        attendanceExpListAdapter = new AttendanceExpandableListAdapter(this.Context, classSectionAttendanceList);
        expListView.SetAdapter(attendanceExpListAdapter);

        expListView.GroupExpand += ExpListView_GroupExpand;
 return rootView;
       }

 private void ExpListView_GroupClick(object sender, ExpandableListView.GroupClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Showing loading progressbar
        progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        DA_ClassSectionAttendance classSectionAttendanceItem = classSectionAttendanceList.ElementAt(e.GroupPosition);


        // start attendencae intent service
        // run Academic Calendar Intent Service
        Intent attendanceIntent = new Intent(this.Context, typeof(AttendanceService));

        // This is just one example of passing some values to an IntentService via the Intent:
        attendanceIntent.PutExtra(AttendanceConstant.KEY_CLASS, classSectionAttendanceItem.ClassId);
        attendanceIntent.PutExtra(AttendanceConstant.KEY_SECTION, classSectionAttendanceItem.SectionId);

        this.Context.StartService(attendanceIntent);
        Log.Debug(Tag, "test:attendance service started");
    }
```

part of Broadcast receiver

```
 private void NotifyAdapterDatasetChanged()
        {
            try
            {
                if (attendanceExpListAdapter == null)
                    return;
                if(!attendanceExpListAdapter.IsEmpty)
                {
                    attendanceExpListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();                       
                }


            }catch(Java.Lang.Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Every time I click on Group Item I get first new AttendanceExpandableListAdapter(this.Context, classSectionAttendanceList) with previous data set but not the updated one which has child items inserted.

And also, at first, when I first create AttendanceExpandableListFragment view, I get a blank screen and in the second time I get group view.

Sample code much is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show your code of `AttendanceExpandableListAdapter`, I didn't see the code how you update data, if your `attendanceExpListAdapter` doesn't change, then `NotifyDataSetChanged` won't work, or are you say that every time you get a new data, you create a new instance of `AttendanceExpandableListAdapter` and set it to the adapter of your expandable listview?

Comment: Yes at the moment I have done same way as you mentioned, every time I get new set of data from web server and create a new instance of **AttendanceExpandableListAdapter** and set it to adapter. Imagine I have a group list of class-section e.g. Ten A is an group item and after I click on it to expand then it hits the intent service to update child items from webserver.

Comment: @IPKaal How u resolved this issue ?